# Can we export multiple non-AMD functions from a module in requirejs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

If I have a non-AMD module named `old.js` and inside this script I have two functions `f1` and `f2` defined. I need to use them, how do I export both?

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min",
    },
    shim: {
        "old": {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: ["f1", "f2"]
        }
    },
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
});
```

This wouldn't work. I will get `split` error. The doc doesn't mention multiple (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) I assume this is because even those jquery examples are individual files and they have "entry" function / class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally, if you want to export more than a single object from a module, you... still need to export a single object. The standard form is to attach your functions to an export object and return that:

```
function f1() { ... }
function f2() { ... }

return {
    f1: f1,
    f2: f2
};
```

If this is non-AMD code, you might not have the `return` statement, but you'd still need to add the export object.

It looks like the [recommended option](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) for old code is to only specify `f1` in the `exports` property, but then do further munging in the `init` function. Presumably require is actually using the `exports` property to check that the file has loaded, so it doesn't matter whether you include all items. Assuming `f1` and `f2` are both globals, you could probably do this:

```
shim: {
    "old": {
        deps: ["jquery"],
        exports: "f1",
        init: function() {
            return {
                f1: f1,
                f2: f2
            };
        }
    }
}
```

This ought to allow you to require `old` and get the export object, rather than `f1`:

```
require(['old'], function(old) {
    old.f1();
    old.f2();
});
```

Comment: Hmm Yeah they are not AMD so they are just regular javascript functions. Are you saying I have to add extra code to old.js file?

Comment: See my edits. I think this is the recommended approach, per the docs, though I haven't tested it.

Comment: Yeah that approach works. Thanks a lot. Am I too sleepy or is the documentation comment under ``init`` in the doc is too confusing? I don't see any specific reference how to deal with the issue. Read the whole shim part 3 times.