# How to use different module names for same URL. There will be different exports from all modules

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs

I have a use case where a file(say **File.js**) contains two different Constructors say **A** and **B**.
I want to write unit tests for both the Constructors present in this file.

But I don't want to make any changes to **File.js** itself. My aim would be to break the File.js into **A.js** and **B.js** but it would be safe to do so only if I have enough testcases for both **A** and **B**.

But at the same time I want to write tests assuming that **A** and **B** are already two different modules. So, I should be able to write the following code.

```
define(['File-A', 'File-B'], function (A, B) {

//Write tests for A

//Write tests for B
})
```

To achieve this I have the following in my requirejs config

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
      'File-A': 'File',
      'File-B': 'File'
    },
    shim: {
      'File-A': {
         exports: 'A'
       },
      'File-B': {
         exports: 'B'
       }
    }
}
```

But I get the following error when doing r.js optimization on it

> The following modules share the same URL. This could be a
>   misconfiguration if that URL only has one anonymous module in it:

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I could get
[Can we export multiple non-AMD functions from a module in requirejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650066/can-we-export-multiple-non-amd-functions-from-a-module-in-requirejs)

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
       File: {
          exports: 'A',
          init: function () {
             return {
                A: A,
                B: B
             };
          }
       }
    }
}


define(['File'], function (AandB) {
 var A = AandB.A,
     B = AandB.B;
//Write tests for A

//Write tests for B
})
```